# Drop null on group by PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a query in Postgres:

```
select gender, avg(x) from db where degree = 'NO' group by gender order by gender
```

Due to some data in x column are NaNs. The result of the group by looks like:

```
'Female','0.12107496463932107496'
'Male','0.09531828898619063658'
 null,'0.10851773264625644135'
```

How to exclude the last rows? the null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition `gender is not null`

```
select gender, avg(x) 
from db where degree = 'NO' and gender is not null
group by gender order by gender
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's missing x values, I think it's missing gender's?

```
select gender, avg(x) from db where degree = 'NO' and gender is not null group by gender order by gender
```